# Flutter build fail. Error in grade: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_local_notifications'

Tags: flutter, gradle, gradlew, flutter-local-notification

I have a problem in my flutter project. The project was fine till I updated my flutter and Android Studio. Now when I build the project it fails. I ran ./gradlew :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace and below is the summary result (I'm not able to post complete output due to character limitation):

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/asifjafry/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_local_notifications-15.1.0+1/android/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_local_notifications'.
> No signature of method: build_6uddu8vjvbut06usixzpkoro1.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_6uddu8vjvbut06usixzpkoro1$_run_closure2) values: [build_6uddu8vjvbut06usixzpkoro1$_run_closure2@32fc9eff]


2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/Users/asifjafry/downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 468

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_local_notifications'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
   > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

Before posting here I have tried following solutions:

1. Check Java version and gradle version
2. Upgraded all the dependencies in pubsec
3. Tried various version of Flutter_Local_Notification
4. Change SDK version (Both compile and target) to 33. Previously it was 31.

Following is the output of by flutter doctor.

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-x64, locale en-IR)
• Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at /Users/asifjafry/downloads/flutter
! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to /Users/asifjafry/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at
  /Users/asifjafry/downloads/flutter. Consider adding /Users/asifjafry/downloads/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /Users/asifjafry/Downloads/flutter/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at
  /Users/asifjafry/downloads/flutter. Consider adding /Users/asifjafry/downloads/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision f468f3366c (3 weeks ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
• Engine revision cdbeda788a
• Dart version 3.0.6
• DevTools version 2.23.1
• If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and upgrades.

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/asifjafry/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.80.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.68.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 115.0.5790.114

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

If any further details are needed, please let me know.